# Option attribute not setting Default value as expected

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I'm simply adding optional command line argument support to my application using the NuGet package CommandLineParser. I'm passing the Options class object into my main application so i can access the necessary values of the object as needed.

**Issue...**

1. The only reason I've moved the Options class outside of the static class Program, is so i can create a variable in other parts of the application called Options and know of the class Options. In doing so i now get the following error. I've noticed that the Options attribute 'Filepath' returns null when it should technically be an empty string. Why is my Default="" not working properly?

> 'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>   'Snipper.Options.Filepath.get returned null

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CommandLine;


    namespace Snipper
    {
        public class Options
        {   
            [Option('f', "filepath", Default = "", Required = false, HelpText = "Set output path, otherwise save in Pictures/Snipper")]
            public string Filepath { get; set; }

            [Option('w', "width", Default = 0, Required = false, HelpText = "Final output resolution width in pixels")]
            public int Width { get; set; }

            [Option('h', "height", Default = 0, Required = false, HelpText = "Final output resolution height in pixels")]
            public int Height { get; set; }
        }

        static class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // do not allow multiple instances of the same program
                if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length > 1)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // Commandline args
                var options = new Options();
                Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args).WithParsed<Options>(opts => options = opts);

                if (options.Filepath.Trim() == "")
                {
                    options.Filepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), "Snipper", "screenshot.png");
                }

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new MainForm(options));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify?  You say "issues", and list one (numbered) issue.  Did you mean to list another?

Comment: I guess, this line making Filepath NULL. This Line -Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args).WithParsed<Options>(opts => options = opts);

Comment: Where is the code of `Option` attribute? You need to check that code to find out why it is not initializing your props with `Default`

Comment: I can only reproduce this if invalid arguments are provided, i.e. argument parsing fails. You should try to spot failures, presumably using `WithNotParsed`, and then not try to use `options` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's `options` and not `Filepath` that's `null`? (edit: I'm sure it's `Filepath` from the onscreen warning you posted)

Try replacing the offending line with `!(String.IsNullOrWhitespace(options?.Filepath))`

Comment: Yeah it appears that the Filepath Option.Attribute's default value of "" is for some reason still returning Null and not being acknowledged as a String value. I'm not sure why that would be...